# MySQL how to concat from two tables to grab the value

Tags: mysql, sql, concatenation

I have 2 tables: product_categories (pc) and product_names (pn). There are 5 product_categories and the product_names table has a field for each of those categories (pn_cat_1, pn_cat_2, pn_cat_3, pn_cat_4 and pn_cat_5). I set the value for each of those pn_cat to '1' if the product has that category. I need to get the product_category for every product name. My current query is below but I'm not getting any output:

```
SELECT * 
FROM 
  product_categories,
  product_names 
WHERE 
  CONCAT('pn_cat_',pc_number) != '0'
GROUP BY pc_cat
```

Comment: Please use a better table design. You're already deep in trouble and this will be worse, if you (or someone else) decide to get a sixth category. Consider using a [junction table](http://stackoverflow.com/tags/junction-table/info).

Comment: Column names cannot be variables in standard SQL, so your use of `CONCAT()` to make a column name is doomed to failure.

Comment: What these two gents said, basically, you can't use concat like you think you can, and your table design is going to land you in trouble.  If we were to just fix this issue tho, you'd have to expand your where statement and use every single field name.  There isn't a way to programmatically compare large amounts of field based off a string pattern, you have to type each one out or use a scripting language to build your query for you.

Comment: I'm confused. Do some products not belong to any category? Otherwise can't you just look at product_names since all the categories are stored in there as fields?